# Macbook Pro wakes and "dings" when plugged in

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, catalina, sleep-wake, power

My macbook pro from mid-2019 "dings" about once a minute when asleep and connected to power.

Logs (they repeat every minute)

```
2020-03-21 13:05:59.499831-0400  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2020-03-21 13:06:00.201815-0400  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver) [HID] [ATC] AppleDeviceManagementHIDEventService::processWakeReason Wake reason: Host (0x01)
2020-03-21 13:06:52.954700-0400  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: XHC2 XHC3 XHC1
2020-03-21 13:06:52.954707-0400  localhost kernel[0]: (AppleACPIPlatform) AppleACPIPlatformPower Wake reason: XHC2 XHC3 XHC1
2020-03-21 13:06:58.252577-0400  localhost corespeechd[1347]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemonMac _isWakeReasonVoiceTrigger] Wake reason: <private>
2020-03-21 13:06:58.252620-0400  localhost corespeechd[1347]: [com.apple.corespeech:Framework] -[CSHostDaemonMac _getPowerAssertionIfWakenByVoiceTriggerNotFromS3Sleep] Wake reason is not VoiceTrigger or it woke from S3
```

I don't *think* it does this at the office, but I don't usually leave it asleep for long periods of time there, so I'm not sure. Now that we're all working from home, it's plugged into my desk all the time.

I have a suspicion that it's the particular power adapter, but wanted some confirmation before purchasing a new one.

Thanks!

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/110702/how-to-know-which-program-has-just-played-sound https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/82987/what-is-causing-this-sound-on-my-mac https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28933/how-can-i-control-sound-from-different-applications